# The separate of K and V is redundant in transformer?

Tags: nlp, transformer

imho, I think the separate of K and V is redundant in transformer, as they are basically the same regardless in encoder self-attention, or decoder self-attention, or even the encoder-decoder attention. Can anyone counter-argue with me, based on the mathematical computation where K, V, Q are done in the training, to disprove my claim?

I would further argue that the preservation of Q, K, V in transformer is just a gimmick to match with the status quo of information retrieval, which adds little sense and brings much confusion to the learners of transformer.

Comment: Being "redundant" seems like a vague description, and it is not expressed in mathematical terms. It would be difficult to mathematically disprove something without a mathematical description of it.

Comment: @noe, ok, so my mathematic formulation is: since K=V regardless in encoder self-attention, or decoder self-attention, or even the encoder-decoder attention. How do they make a difference mathematically speaking during training?

Comment: While I understand your point, I think that the purpose of having different names ("keys" and "values") for the same data is there to make it clearer the two different roles the data play inside the attention computation.